# Configuring SSL on Nifi 1.9 Single Node setup

Tags: apache-nifi

Could you please help me setup the SSL on the Nifi Application.
To explain about the steps taken so far.

I have used the following link intructions to use the CA signed certs provided to us (This include root,intermediate and Server cert). I have sucessfully configured Nifi to run on SSL on server end but i am not getting the steps to create a client cert so that using the client cert we can login to Nifi.

Help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Where is the link?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to generate a Certificate Signing Request (CSR) or request from your security/IT team who provided the CA-signed server certs that they provide a client certificate (and private key) signed by the same intermediate or root CA. You could also generate your own client certificate signed by a self-signed CA and put the public certificate of that CA in the NiFi truststore. More documentation around this process can be found in the [NiFi Toolkit Guide](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/toolkit-guide.html#tls_toolkit).

Comment: @Andi Thanks.  I am getting the following error when i am trying to reach the nifi https url .
 didn’t accept your login certificate, or one may not have been provided.
 ERR_BAD_SSL_CLIENT_AUTH_CERT
 I have used the below command to import client cert in trustore after generating the client cert using toolkit
 
 Imported the client .crt file into the trustore of nifi.
 keytool -import -alias clientcert -file CN=kylo_OU=NIFI.crt -storetype JKS -keystore truststore.jks

Comment: Can someone please help me with the steps to create a client cert and then add in my already existing trustore of Nifi. This is urgent.